# Java load library with variable

Tags: java, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a library by using the System.load() function and a variable.
It works when I load the library in each function but I want to be able to do it with one general system load, similar to what you do when you load with a known library path.

```
    static{
           System.load("/libraryPath/libLibrary.so");
    }
```

However it is not possible to give a static variable to this System.load as it will not be instantiated by the time the load is called.
Any ideas?
Thank you

**EDIT**

I have found a solution,
I ended up using a static getter in a different class.
This has the advantage that I can parse a config file where I store the location. Store the variable, and retrieve it using a static method in the class were I need the library. Now I can do a general load like this:

```
    static{
        System.load(OtherClass.getLibrary());
    }
```

thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static code is executed in the order of declaration so you need to declare the variable before your static code block. This is why often static code blocks are problematic and better replaced with a different formalism.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I'm using everywhere to load native code.
I hope it will help you.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class NativeLoader {

/** Directory containing native libraries */
private static final String NATIVE_LIBS_DIRECTORY = "/native/"; 

/** Extension for temporary file containing extracted native library */
private static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_EXT = ".tmp"; 

    /**
     * Loads a native library
     *  
     * @param libraryName
     *            name of the native library to load
     * @throws IOException
     *             if the native library cannot be loaded
     */
    public static void loadEmbeddedLibrary(String libraryName) throws IOException {

        String mapName = System.mapLibraryName(libraryName);
        InputStream is = NativeLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(NATIVE_LIBS_DIRECTORY + mapName);

        if (is != null) {
            File native_library = File.createTempFile(mapName, TEMPORARY_FILE_EXT);
            native_library.deleteOnExit();
            native_library.setWritable(true);
            native_library.setExecutable(true);

            if (native_library.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(native_library);
                int read;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                os.close();
                is.close();

                System.load(native_library.getPath());
            }
            else {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you like to be sure that the call to

```
System.load("/libraryPath/libLibrary.so");
```

has been done before using it in different portions of your code.

If you create a class to do that like the following you should obtain that.

```
public class Loader {
    static {
        System.load("/libraryPath/libLibrary.so");
    }

    public static void init() {
    }
}
```

and in you code before using the library:

```
Loader.init();
// Code using native library
```

This will ensure that the library will be loaded only once, but you are also sure that it has been loaded before using it.

The method `init()` is a trick to be sure that the class Loader is effectively loaded in memory. The only `import` statement is not enough to be sure that the `static` init will be executed.